# displaying the hour and minute with mobiscroll

Tags: angular, date, mobiscroll

Is there a way to display the hour and minute with mobiscroll? I can show the year/month/day,but i don't know how to display the hour and minute,here's my code

```js
$scope.endDate = {
  preset: 'datetime',
  theme: 'mobiscroll',
  display: 'bottom',      
  minDate: new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()),       
  setText: '确定',
  cancelText: '取消',
  //amText: '上午',
  //[enter image description here][1]pmText: '下午',
  dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',  
  timeFormat:'HH:ii:ss',
  dateOrder: 'yymmddDD',
  timeOrder:'HHiiss',
  lang: 'zh',     
  dayNames: ['星期日', '星期一', '星期二', '星期三', '星期四', '星期五', '星期六'],      
  headerText: '{value}',
  buttons: [
    'set',
    'cancel'
  ],
  onSelect: function (valueText, inst) {
    $scope.examForm.examTime = valueText;
    $scope.$apply();
    }
};
```

```html
<input ng-model="endTime" mobiscroll-date="endDate" type="text" mobiscroll-instance="endDate" name="endDate" readonly ng-value="releaseForm.endTime"  class="datapicker"/>
```

Comment: Please specify the mobiscroll version you are using. Did you tried adding `timeWheels: 'HHii'` property?

Comment: thanks for your kind answer,I use the v2.17.1, it is said the preset parameter is Invalid in this version, so no matter what i set, this patameter  show date, the hour and minute don't show, I alse tried timeWheels:'HHii',but it alse show this way.

Comment: I think this was enabled at 2.17.3 try to upgrade to that version.

Comment: i find the v2.17.1 is enabled in a demo, u mean just add timeWheels maybe  not enabled